# Como fazer um programa em Java pesquisar em um arquivo certa informação e retornar uma string

Tags: java

Olá. Eu tenho um programa que teria que pesquisar em um arquivo de texto como esse:

```
ovelha animal
gato animal
joão humano
arvore planta
```

Eu preciso de um método, que recebendo uma string, avalia com base nesse arquivo se essa string está lá, por exemplo o método recebe a string "gato", que está lá então ele retorna a string "animal", se recebesse a string "joão" retornaria a string "humano", e assim por diante, mas se recebesse algo que não está na lista, retornaria "erro", ou algo do tipo. Eu não faço idéia de como fazer isso :P Desde já obrigado

Comment: Oi, 1º: Você utiliza a classe File para buscar pelo arquivo.2º você ter que "ler" o arquivo e então utilizar métodos como contains ou indexOf da classe String para verificar a informação que procura.

Comment: Você pode tentar passar cada linha do seu arquivo para uma `String`, que por sua vez, seria adicionada em uma `List<String>`. Feito isso, você terá que fazer o tratamento da seguinte forma: pegar o que tem antes do espaço em branco (pesquise por `trim()`) e fazer a comparação dentro de um laço de repetição (`for` ou `while` da vida). Quando existir correspondência, pegue o que sobrou da `String` (desprezar o que tem antes do espaço em branco) e use como seu retorno. PS: Estou no caminho de casa e não tive como explicitar com código, mas espero que a linha de pensamento lhe ajude.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.FileReader;
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class Teste {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        String chave = "gato";
        String local = "C:\\Users\\kcpo\\Desktop\\farm.txt";
        System.out.println(getValor(chave, local));
    }
    private static String getValor(String chave, String local)
            throws FileNotFoundException {
        String valor = "";
        Scanner in = new Scanner(new FileReader(local));
        while (in.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = in.nextLine();
            String[] linha = line.split(" ");

            if (linha[0].equals(chave)) {
                valor = linha[1];
                break;
            } else {
                valor = "erro";
            }
        }
        return valor;
    }
}
```

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou aqui!